# Listing awarded grants not affiliated with a university research position on a CV

Tags: funding, cv, job, academic-life

I've had a look around but couldn't find an answer to my question. I'm in the process of updating my CV and am wondering about how to list grants awarded, specifically grants awarded to a group of people at a not-for-profit institution in which I am/was involved with. This involvement is outside of my current role as a teaching/research academic and is entirely voluntary.

E.G. 1: For one not-for-profit, I completed the research component that enabled the organisation to seek funding to support their project. Would this count towards a grant awarding or no?

E.G. 2: I'm currently involved with a not-for-profit organisation that received government funding for a particular project that I currently manage/was involved in the initial set up in. We've just been informed that the funding will be renewed (which is very exciting). As an organisation (and not a single person) we sought the funding together (it's a very small org, there's about 6 people in total involved). Would I list this as perhaps a group project?

Any tips, feedback or suggestions would be helpful!

(this answer was close but not exactly what I was looking for...[Conventions regarding listing grant applications/funded grants on a scientific CV](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/25808/conventions-regarding-listing-grant-applications-funded-grants-on-a-scientific-c))

Answer (score 2):

Your CV is a list of all of your scientific credentials, not just all of the credentials that you happen to have gathered while in a university research position.  Whether you obtain your grant at a university, a non-profit, or a for-profit company, in all cases it shows evidence of your ability to engage with funders and obtain external support for research, education, outreach, technology transition, or other such activities that are important in academia.  Certainly, for my own part as a scientist working at a for-profit company, I quite comfortably and proudly list the funding that I have obtained for my work on my CV.

Comment: But what if the work is not just 'my' work but rather, part of a larger project/initiative? In the first case, I did the research and analysis, but I didn't write the funding application. In the second, I helped put together the application with others for the outreach program and currently manage this program, but its not under *our* individual names but rather, the name of the organisation of which I am a part of? Would it still count as credentials?

Comment: @awsoci When I list grants on my CV, I list a set of "authors", which is at least the set of PIs and any other major authors that I am aware of.  I don't know whether that's "conventional" but I think the meaning is clear.

Comment: But there are not direct authors or private investigators. So unlike perhaps research grants within an academic or scientific setting, these are grants awarded to social outreach programs in which research was used to help support the application. So the authors are listed as the organisation, as opposed to individual people? So would then I put the organisation or provide a description of my role?

Comment: @awsoci At the end of the day, the goal of a CV is communication of your professional accomplishments.  If you feel this grant reflects an accomplishment on your part, explain how in a manner that allows the reader to understand and judge for themselves, even if it doesn't fit a standard template.