# If I'm key personnel on an NIH grant . . . can I put that on my CV?

Tags: funding, postdocs, cv, awards, nih

I'm a postdoc in the sciences.

My supervisor submitted a grant renewal to the NIH recently and listed me as "key personnel" on it.  The renewal received very high marks and is likely to be approved.

Although I have received fellowships in the past, I've never applied for a grant, and I've never been key personnel on a grant before.

Would it be appropriate for me to list on my CV that I'm key personnel on this grant (if the renewal is officially approved)?  If so, how should this be stated?  Examples from actual CVs would be much appreciated.  (To be specific, I'm not sure whether I should list this alongside my fellowships, in my "Awards" section . . . or start an entirely new section for "Grants" or something like that.)

**EDIT**: This question is similar in flavor to [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/25808/35513), but I'm looking for a more specific answer than that question received . . . It's possible this should be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think I've found what I'm looking for, but I'm still interested in other answers/feedback.

I think a new section in my CV that looks like this would be appropriate:

> **Grants**
>
> - National Institutes of Health, AXZ-1394 (2018-2021)
>
>   "Awesome Grant Title"
>
>   Role:   Key Personnel

Comment: Good answer, and [it's explicitly encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :D

Answer (score 9):

> Would it be appropriate for me to list on my CV that I'm key personnel on this grant (if the renewal is officially approved)?

My answer to this, like all CV questions, is which CV. I have a big CV which has everything on it (including failed grant proposals for which I was listed as key personnel). I then delete things as I tailor the CV to a specific purpose. Every once in a while you will get an odd request from your department about things like *we need a list of every grant application you have been involved with in the past 10 years by tomorrow*. Having a single CV that I can cut from is much easier than going through all my files on my computer.

The next question then becomes, how useful is it to let people know that you were a key personnel on a grant. The answer is it depends on your funding history and what you are applying for. In my opinion, the extent to which not having applied for much funding will hurt you will depend on your role in the funding you have had (being a key personnel on a single grant is much better than having been shuttled from grant to grant and never named).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it’s good to do so, and don’t be afraid to put all your grant/funding activities up front and center, even before your pubs. I’d put them all together under a more general ‘external funding’ section.